# Google Maps API - Number of customers for places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm reading the documentation of GM-APIs, I found the section relative to "Places", but I can't find anything to get the information about the per-hour number of customers for a certain place.

Do you know whenever you search a place on GMaps, there is an indication of the frequency of customers, in that way you can know if the place will be busy or empty. 
Is there any way to retrieve that information through Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no available feature in Google Maps API that could get the exact number or the of people in an establishment to determine its busiest time of the day.

However, there is an existing Feature Request in Google Map Platform's Public issue tracker to expose the place's popular times which seems to be related to the feature you are looking for.

Here's the link to that feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/35827350. You can star/favorite this feature request and feel free to leave a comment there regarding your use case for additional information as well.